# MongoDB querying on a list

Tags: mongodb

I would like to make a query which gets a list and returns all the documanets that are contained in the list in the requested field.

**For example:**

If I have two documents:

Document 1

```
{
    "list":["a","b","c"]
}
```

Document 2

```
{
    "list":["c","d","e"]
}
```

In case of the list `["a","b","c"]` the first document should return

In case of the list `["a","b","c","d"]` the first document should return

In case of the list `["a","c"]` none should return

In case of the list `["a","b","c","d","e"]` both should return

Comment: What code have you tried to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with aggregation framework - much faster and better than using Javascript.

```
var yourList = ["a", "b", etc ] // your list here
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match:{list:{$in:yourList}}}, 
    {$project:{originalList:"$list",list:1}},
    {$unwind:"$list"}, 
    {$match:{list:{$in:yourList}}},
    {$group:{_id:"$_id",list:{$push:"$list"}, originalList:{$first:"$originalList"}}}, 
    {$project:{keep:{$eq:["$list","$originalList"]},list:1}},
    {$match:{keep:true}}
] );
```

You can add another `$project` step to get rid of "keep" field.  Obviously any other fields in the documents you want to have selected at the end also need to be carried through the projections and grouping stage.